# In nested stack navigation in react-navigation. it does not to scroll up

Tags: react-navigation

I have a problem.
I had coded react-native and react-navigation.

In 'HOME' screen, I had scrolled down, and When I had pressed the icon 'HOME',

There are no any changes to scroll.

Certainly, I have used 'ref - useScrollToTop method', But I cannot go to screen up

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.screen name='home' component={HomeNavigation} options={{ <Image ...(blah blah) /> }} />
</Tab.Navigator>
----
<HomeNavigation.Navigator initialRouteName="Main" name="Main" component={HomeTopTabNavigation}>
  <HomeNavigation.Screen name="Main" component={HomeTopTabNavigation} />
<HomeNavigation.Navigator />
----
<HomeTopTabNavigation.Navigator initialRouteName='NEW'>
  <HomeTopTabNavigation.Screen name="NEW" component={Home} />
  <HomeTopTabNavigation.Screen name="HOT" component={HOT} />
</HomeTopTabNavigation.Navigator>
----
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);    *******.  This ref does not work ! 
  useScrollToTop(ref);            *******.  This ref does not work ! 
...
  return (
    ...
    <FlatList 
      ref ={ref}                 *******.  This ref does not work !               
      ...
    />
  )
}
```

[more specific navigation name in this picture. please see this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27wES.png)